# how to re-bind click() event after using "datatables" search

Tags: jquery

I have a table that I'm displaying using datatables.  One of the columns in the table is a checkbox.  Checking (or unchecking) the checkbox causes an Ajax event.  Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".data-table").dataTable({});
    $(".my-checkbox").click(function() {
       $.ajax(....)
    })
  })
</script>

<table class="data-table">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox"></td>
  </tr>

  <!-- repeat many times -->
</table>
```

This works great on the initial page load, but as soon as I use the "search" box, the change() method is unbound from anything found by search.

Is there an API hook that I can use to re-bind my click() handler to the checkboxes once the search is complete?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: Are you missing some code? I don't see you binding the `change` event anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.click is a shortcut to .bind, which bind only for elements in the page. You have to use .live:

```
$('.my-checkbox').live('click', handler);
```

Another option is to use delegate:

```
$('.data-table').delegate('.my-checkbox', 'click', handler);
```

**Update:** as of jQuery 1.7+, both `.live` and `.delegate` have been deprecated and superseded with `.on`:

```
$('.my-checkbox').on('click', handler);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the datatable loads the rows dynamically.
Re-bind the events on draw of the datatable, unbinding any old events first.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var dataTable = $(".data-table").dataTable();
      // draw will be called when paging/filtering
      dataTable.on('draw', function() {
        bindEvents();
      });
      dataTable.draw();

    });
    function bindEvents() {
        // Unbind any old events first
        $(".my-checkbox").off('click');
        $(".my-checkbox").on('click', function() {
          $.ajax(....)
        });
      })
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can re-bind it manually or use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".data-table").dataTable({});
    $(".my-checkbox").live('click', function() {
       $.ajax(....)
    })
  });
```